# Cannot compile: using try_buffer_unordered with StreamExt map

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I'm trying to use StreamExt and TryStreamExt as follows:

```
use tokio::fs::File;
use tokio::io::{self, AsyncReadExt};
use futures::stream::{self, StreamExt, TryStreamExt};

async fn read_file(name: &str) -> io::Result<[u8; 10]> {
    let mut f = File::open(name).await?;
    let mut buffer = [0; 10];
   
    // read up to 10 bytes... yes I know this is not safe but...
    let n = f.read(&mut buffer[..]).await?;
    Ok(buffer)    
} 

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let files = vec!["foo.txt", "bar.txt"];
    let headers = stream::iter(files)
        .map(|f| {
            tokio::spawn(
                read_file(f)
            )
        })
        .try_buffer_unordered(8)
        .try_collect()?;
    println!("Got results: {:?}", headers);
    Ok(())
}
```

A link to the playground is here:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3edf39926c3f046f89f2d925f1a93115

The result of the async_fn and the `tokio::spawn` is a `Result<Result<...., MyError>, JoinError>.`    The try_buffer_unordered does not compile after a map, which I cannot figure out.   I get:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0599]: no method named `try_buffer_unordered` found for struct `futures::stream::Map<futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<&str>>, [closure@src/main.rs:19:14: 23:10]>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:24:10
   |
24 |           .try_buffer_unordered(8)
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `futures::stream::Map<futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<&str>>, [closure@src/main.rs:19:14: 23:10]>`
   | 
  ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.13/src/stream/stream/map.rs:12:1
   |
12 | / pin_project! {
13 | |     /// Stream for the [`map`](super::StreamExt::map) method.
14 | |     #[must_use = "streams do nothing unless polled"]
15 | |     pub struct Map<St, F> {
...  |
19 | |     }
20 | | }
   | | -
   | | |
   | |_doesn't satisfy `_: TryStreamExt`
   |   doesn't satisfy `_: TryStream`
   |
   = note: the method `try_buffer_unordered` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `futures::stream::Map<futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<&str>>, [closure@src/main.rs:19:14: 23:10]>: TryStream`
           which is required by `futures::stream::Map<futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<&str>>, [closure@src/main.rs:19:14: 23:10]>: TryStreamExt`
           `&futures::stream::Map<futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<&str>>, [closure@src/main.rs:19:14: 23:10]>: TryStream`
           which is required by `&futures::stream::Map<futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<&str>>, [closure@src/main.rs:19:14: 23:10]>: TryStreamExt`
           `&mut futures::stream::Map<futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<&str>>, [closure@src/main.rs:19:14: 23:10]>: TryStream`
           which is required by `&mut futures::stream::Map<futures::stream::Iter<std::vec::IntoIter<&str>>, [closure@src/main.rs:19:14: 23:10]>: TryStreamExt`
```

I could use buffer_unordered() but then I'm left with a stream with a double nested Result
and I was hoping to use try_buffer_unordered and try_collect().... any thoughts?
(Yes I know the read code has problems, it's just to illustrate the compile problem with StreamExt

(The alternative is something like a series of collects to try to get rid of the Results, which is ugly and uses up extra collections)

Comment: It seems the return value from .map() doesn't satisfy the constraints for the TryStream trait, and using tokio::spawn() inside doesn't seem right either.  Can you please provide more details about the contents of the vec![], and the code inside the closure and async move blocks so I can try it out on my end?

Comment: `map` expects a plain function, not an async one. Did you mean to use [`then`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.then)?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) if possible then edit your question to include the additional info.

Comment: @kmdreko I included a working playground to repro the compile error.  What I'm trying to do is to use map() to get results from a whole bunch of work (say I/O work) that needs to be done in parallel, and try_buffer_unordered to control the parallelism, and unwrap the JoinError.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, what I was told from Tokio discord is that one cannot use `try_buffer_unordered` with a regular `Future` returned from a `map`.  The `try_*` methods are intended for when the creation of the `Future` might not succeed, in other words something like a `Result<Future, _>`.

Answer (score 0):

The double `Result` (`Result<Result<_, _>, _>`) is coming from wrapping your call to `read_file()` (which returns `Result`) in `tokio::spawn()`, which [wraps the return value of the spawned `Future` in a `Result`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html#associatedtype.Output). That can be seen by looking at the return type of this:

```rust
tokio::spawn(read_file("foo.txt")).await
```

([Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=95caaa2ba252a5d1a79ff40e73064ece))

---

I don't know what the ultimate goal is, here, but one option is to not wrap the `read_file()` `Future` in `tokio::span()`. Wrapping those `Future`s in [`tokio::spawn()` will run each of those futures in the background immediately](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.spawn.html), regardless of the buffer size passed to `.buffer_unordered()`. That may not be what's desired.

Instead, [let `.buffer_unordered()` handle the concurrency](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffer_unordered).

That solution can look like this:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let files = vec!["foo.txt", "bar.txt"];
    let headers: Vec<_> = stream::iter(files)
        .map(read_file)
        .buffer_unordered(8)
        .try_collect()
        .await?;
    println!("Got results: {:?}", headers);
    Ok(())
}
```

([Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9cb0fcc75117b2389c075e745979a33f))

An alternative approach would be to map `Result<Result<_, _> _>` into a `Result<_, _>`, which requires mapping the errors down to a single type. The outcome of that is deceptive, though. Even though a single error would ultimately be returned, the other `Future`s will still run (and may also error). You can see that in the output [here in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e744f667ab036e71502c8dbade74e9f). Compare that output with what happens when [not using `tokio::spawn()`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ce25fa37464eee8353d8322cc82a781).